# Can you run a transactional data lake (Hudi, Delta Lake) with multiple EMR clusters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, delta-lake, apache-hudi

I’m looking into several “transactional data lake” technologies such as Apache Hudi, Delta Lake, AWS Lake Formation Governed Tables.

Except for the latter, I can’t see how these would work in a multi cluster environment. I’m baselining against s3 for storage, and want to incrementally alter my data lake, where I may have many clusters all reading from and writing to the lake at any given time. Is this possible/supported? It seems like the compaction and transaction processes are on-cluster. And so you cannot manage a transactional data lake with these platforms from multiple disparate sources.  Or am I mistaken?

Any anecdotes or performance limitations you’ve found would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you thinking that in a multi cluster env that compaction and transaction would somehow ruin consistency? Traditional RDBMS have solved these concerns for a while and now Hudi and Delta Lake are taking a similar approach.

Comment: It could work. Only with a centralized metastore, which is what I’m looking for information on.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable a config for multiple writers on Apache Hudi and then use a lock provider as described here: https://hudi.apache.org/docs/concurrency_control#enabling-multi-writing

Example using an AWS DynamoDB lock provider:

```
hoodie.write.lock.provider=org.apache.hudi.aws.transaction.lock.DynamoDBBasedLockProvider
hoodie.write.lock.dynamodb.table
hoodie.write.lock.dynamodb.partition_key
hoodie.write.lock.dynamodb.region
```

Delta Lake has a warning in the documentation that multiple writers may result in data loss:
https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html#amazon-s3

> Concurrent writes to the same Delta table from multiple Spark drivers can lead to data loss.

[This is a blog](https://www.onehouse.ai/blog/lakehouse-concurrency-control-are-we-too-optimistic) you may find interesting that discusses common pitfalls in Lakehouse concurrency control.

Comment: So the answer is no.